# Pass a string or array as arguments in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, grep

I have `excludes` as a variable, where it's meant to be a list of regexes to pass to grep:

```
$ echo $excludes
-e re_1 -e re_2 -e re_3...
```

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
$ my | pipeline | grep -v "${excludes}"
```

but this doesn't work.

I also tried using an array as in `grep -v "${excludes[@]}"` where each array member is "-e blah".  This didn't work either.

How can I pass arguments in a programmatic way like this?

Comment: I think this may be one of the cases where you should not quote your variable.

Comment: @Jesse_b, only works if the regexes don't contain whitespace, and they'd get used as globs too (unless `set -f`), which isn't likely to be good since regexes often contain the very same characters that are special in globs...

Comment: Where do your regexes come from? A space-separated string like that seems fiddly if you ever happen to need regexes that contain spaces...

Comment: I control the source of the regexes, so that's not an issue in this case.  choroba's answer was what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array works, but you need to store the options and values as separate elements:

```
excludes=(-e "regex1" -e "regex2")
grep -v "${excludes[@]}" ...
```