# Invoke a program in a Bash script with command line parameters stored in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, options

Is it possible to invoke some program in a Bash script with complete command line parameters (both the key and the value) stored in variables?

I use the following `scanimage` call in a script:

```
scanimage -p --mode "True Gray" --resolution 150 -l 0 -t 0 -x 210 -y 297 --format=png  -o scan.png
```

I want to store some of the parameters in variables. I tried this, concerning the `--mode` switch:

```
options="--mode \"True Gray\""
scanimage -p $options --resolution 150 -l 0 -t 0 -x 210 -y 297 --format=png  -o scan.png
```

but this doesn't work, `scanimage` says:

```
scanimage: setting of option --mode failed (Invalid argument)
```

Storing only the value for the `--mode` switch does work:

```
mode="True Gray"
scanimage -p --mode "$mode" --resolution 150 -l 0 -t 0 -x 210 -y 297 --format=png  -o scan.png
```

but I'd like to be variable about the switches, and I'd also like to customize multiple switches without knowing which will be set.

So is it possible to store not only the values for command line options in a variable, but also the option switch(es) along with the value(s)?

Comment: Run `set -x` in your terminal and then try the command again and post the output. That will show us exactly what is being passed to the `scanimage` command. I am guessing it will be `'--mode' '"True' 'Gray"'`.

Comment: Yes, exactly! `+ scanimage -p --mode '"True' 'Gray"' ...`

Comment: Use an array, with separate elements for each option and its argument. See for example [Pass a string or array as arguments in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409290/pass-a-string-or-array-as-arguments-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you use an array instead of a string. Try this:

```
options=( '--mode' "True Gray" )
scanimage -p "${options[@]}" --resolution 150 -l 0 -t 0 -x 210 -y 297 --format=png  -o scan.png
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a lot :-)